# Android loop to check tablelayout not incrementing through children

Tags: java, android, for-loop, increment

I am working on a basic connect 3/tic tac toe app.
At the start of the app I want to run a method to get the number of buttons that make up the grid, so in future I could use the same code to scale up the grid size.
I have a method, `getBoardSize` that should return an integer to set the length of an array.
The problem I am having is that the `buttonCount` variable is not incrementing. Just testing at the moment with having the method count only the first button, but it is not seeing it.
I am printing the various values to the logs and whilst I can see the counter changing, it does not seem to be going through and checking the children, or there is something wrong with my comparison.
I am expecting it to return `9`.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.richardcurteis.connect3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    boolean noughtsTurn;
    char board[];

    public void onClick(View view) {
        String gridNumber = (String) view.getTag();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        boolean noughtsTurn = true;
        char board[] = new char[getBoardSize()];
        System.out.println("Board length: " + board.length);
    }

    public int getBoardSize() {
        int buttonCount = 0;
        TableLayout layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        System.out.println("Table child count: " + layout.getChildCount());
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Value of i: " + i);
            View view = layout.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof Button && view.getId() == R.id.gridButton1 ) {
                buttonCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Child count: " + buttonCount);
        return buttonCount;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.richardcurteis.connect3.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:background="#070000">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:background="#000000">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton1"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:onClick="getInput"
                android:tag="0" />
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton2"
                android:layout_column="12"
                android:onClick="getInput"
                android:tag="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton3"
                android:layout_column="19"
                android:tag="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton4"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:tag="3"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton5"
                android:layout_column="12"
                android:tag="4"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton6"
                android:layout_column="19"
                android:tag="5"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton7"
                android:layout_column="4"
                android:tag="6"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton8"
                android:layout_column="12"
                android:tag="7"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/gridButton9"
                android:layout_column="19"
                android:tag="8" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <Button

        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:text="New Game"
        android:id="@+id/newGameButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Log output :**

```
12-30 23:05:24.407 15382-15382/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-30 23:05:24.541 15382-15389/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
12-30 23:05:24.554 15382-15382/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.richardcurteis.connect3-2/lib/x86
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Table child count: 20
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 0
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 1
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 2
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 3
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 4
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 5
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 6
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 7
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 8
12-30 23:05:24.679 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 9
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 10
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 11
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 12
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 13
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 14
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 15
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 16
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 17
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 18
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Value of i: 19
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Child count: 0
12-30 23:05:24.680 15382-15382/? I/System.out: Board length: 0
12-30 23:05:24.683 15382-15396/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-30 23:05:24.837 15382-15396/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-30 23:05:24.903 15382-15396/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-30 23:05:24.903 15382-15396/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7f5880, error=EGL_SUCCESS.
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above code you are counting childs of tableLayout, which first child of topmost layout.
All the childs of that tableLayout are of tableRow type, so

```
view instanceof Button will return false
```

And so buttonCount is not incremented.

Instead go to grandchilds of tableLayout and count them.

For example

```
public int getBoardSize() {
        int buttonCount = 0;
        TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        for(int rowIndex=0; rowIndex<tableLayout.getChildCount(); rowIndex++){
            View tableLayoutChild = tableLayout.getChildAt(rowIndex);
            if(tableLayoutChild instanceof TableRow){
                for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup)tableLayoutChild).getChildCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Value of button child i: " + i);
                    View view = ((ViewGroup)tableLayoutChild).getChildAt(i);
                    if (view instanceof Button && view.getId() == R.id.gridButton1 ) {
                        buttonCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println("Child count: " + buttonCount);
        return buttonCount;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that's spot on. I wasn't iterating through the tablerows properly following the tablelayout.
Thanks for the help